# specifying html markup when using Laravel scaffolding

Tags: html, laravel, scaffolding

Ive built the all the views (html, css, jquery) for a web app and now im starting work on the back end, using Laravel / Mysql.

I recently came across [scaffolding in Laravel](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u9SShBRZtEw), similar to Ruby on Rails, which is great, but the forms ive built for my views all contain special classes and markup is there a way to specify the classes and other markup to be applied to form when using scaffolding ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you correctly, you can set an extra variable on controller, or check URI or route on views, and specify extra classes by looking to the view.

E.g: In the controller, you can do something like this:

```
return View::make('views.myview')->with('type','form');
```

And in the view, you can use simple if clause(s):

```
@if(isset($type))
    <div class="{{$type}}">
@else
    <div class="default">
@endif
```

For adding extra markup and assets to views, I use `teeplus/asset`, which is ported from Laravel 3 to 4 (old habits die hard :)).

[packagist URL](https://packagist.org/packages/teepluss/asset)

[documentation](http://three.laravel.com/docs/views/assets)